# Kaleo workflow: Multiple notification onEntry

Tags: liferay, workflow

In my Kaleo workflow, one task have to two notification first is user-notification and second mail.
Both notification are set on Entry, in this scenario one first notification got and second is not send.

I want both notification on task entry.

My action block is like below.

```
<actions>
    <notification>
        <name>Name</name>
        <description>Description</description>
        <template>Mail Template</template>
        <template-language>freemarker</template-language>
        <notification-type>email</notification-type>
        <recipients receptionType="cc">
            <roles>
                <role>
                    <role-type>regular</role-type>
                    <name>Contract Management</name>
                    <auto-create>true</auto-create>
                </role>
                <role>
                    <role-type>regular</role-type>
                    <name>FSO</name>
                    <auto-create>true</auto-create>
                </role>
                <role>
                    <role-type>regular</role-type>
                    <name>Accounting</name>
                    <auto-create>true</auto-create>
                </role>
            </roles>
        </recipients>
        <execution-type>onEntry</execution-type>
    </notification>
    <notification>
        <name>Name</name>
        <template>You assigned new task, please check.</template>
        <template-language>text</template-language>
        <notification-type>user-notification</notification-type>
        <execution-type>onEntry</execution-type>
    </notification>
</actions>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<task>
 <actions>
   <notification>
       <name>Name</name>
       <description>Description</description>
       <template>Mail Template</template>
       <template-language>freemarker</template-language>
       <notification-type>email</notification-type>
        <recipients receptionType="cc">
         <roles>
            <role>
                <role-type>regular</role-type>
                <name>Contract Management</name>
                <auto-create>true</auto-create>
            </role>
            <role>
                <role-type>regular</role-type>
                <name>FSO</name>
                <auto-create>true</auto-create>
            </role>
            <role>
                <role-type>regular</role-type>
                <name>Accounting</name>
                <auto-create>true</auto-create>
            </role>
        </roles>
    </recipients>
    <execution-type>onEntry</execution-type>
</notification>
<!-- <notification>
    <name>Name</name>
    <template>You assigned new task, please check.</template>
    <template-language>text</template-language>
    <notification-type>user-notification</notification-type>
    <execution-type>onEntry</execution-type>
</notification> -->
</actions>
<assignment />
<task-timers>
        <task-timer>
            <name>Other Notifications</name>
            <delay>
                <duration>1</duration>
                <scale>second</scale>
            </delay>
            <blocking>false</blocking>
            <timer-actions>
                <timer-notification>
                    <name>Name</name>
                    <template>Your template</template>
                    <template-language>freemarker</template-language>
                    <notification-type>user-notification</notification-type>
                </timer-notification>
            </timer-actions>
        </task-timer>
    </task-timers>
 <transitions />
</task>
```

Comment: Thank @Prabhpreet